# Dismantling and reassembling polyline by joining each point to its nearest neighboring point using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, geometry

How can I reconfigure a PolylineMZ feature class in a way as shown in the image below?

I have a feature class (PolylineMZ) which contains x-sections. Some x-sections (polylines) are badly constructed (as shown below in figure "a"), so I want to dismantle and reassemble them again in the right order. By "right order", I mean that I want to join the points that are closest to each other (as shown below in figure "b").

Any idea for an existing tool? Preferably in Arc 10.

[image: 3 polylines with vertex points]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make [feature vertices to point](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003p000000) then use this tool test this tool [Point to line](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003s000000.htm)

you may need to save the original polyline attribute to use it as Line_Field , if you have intersecting lines and the distance between them is greater than the distance between each point and another.

Comment: Its not exactly what I was looking for but it will do the trick after some tweaking. Below some more details.

Answer (score 2):

As per above answer: [Feature vertices to point](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003p000000) and [Point to line](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003s000000.htm) will work, if we have calculated proper sequence of points in the XSection. Probably there is few ways of achiving this. I decided to use [Sort](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000057000000) which helps me to sort  points by section (unique ID of XS) and X coords within the section. In my case it is good enough to use X coords as all sections are in more/less the same direction. When objects are sorted from min. X coord. to max. X coord. just populate new field with unique ID (Field Calculator). Ie.:

Pre-logic:

```
counter = 0
def uniqueID():
  global counter
  counter += 1
  return counter
```

Execution:

```
uniqueID()
```

After this I could use [Point to line](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003s000000.htm) tool.